# Set parent controls property in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a panel with a custom `ListView`. The `ListView's` items contains a `GroupBox`. The `GroupBox` contains a `ListView`. This `ListView's` items contains a `GroupBox` and so on.

All of the controls above have custom templates and styles

There are `ToggleButtons` in the Controls VisualTree lowest nodes.
When these buttons are checked I need to disable all the panel except of the button was clicked.

I would like to avoid event chaining through the parents in viewModel classes.

I'm using mvvm pattern and I would like to solve it in the xaml side if its possible.

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot and the Pick button should disable the panel

[image]

Any suggestions are warmly welcomed.

Comment: could you put a shot of your view ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement the relative source binding something like below.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=IsEnabled}"
```

Comment: This will bind the child to the parent's property

Answer (score 0):

Just have a read-only property in your ViewModel that is the negation of the property that your ToggleButton is bound to.

**ViewModel:**

```
private Boolean mSourceIsPicked;
public Boolean SourceIsPicked
{
    get { return mSourceIsPicked; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty("SourceIsPicked", ref mSourceIsPicked, value); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSourceChangeable");
    }
}

public Boolean IsSourceChangeable
{
    get { return ! this.SourceIsPicked; }
}
```

Then, in your View, just bind the IsEnabled property of the other controls to that new property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceTypes}"
          IsEnabled={Binding IsSourceChangeable}" />
```

The advantage of binding to a property is that you can add/remove controls in your view and just bind to this property without changing additional XAML.  You can also change the behavior of any control by *not* binding to this property.

If you really want a XAML-only solution, you can name each of the controls in the panel, and use a DataTrigger using TargetName on the "SourceIsPicked" property to disable the others:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboSourceTypes" ... />
<ComboBox x:Name="cboSourceNames" ... />
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SourceIsPicked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="cboSourceTypes" 
                            Property="IsEnabled" 
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter TargetName="cboSourceNames" 
                            Property="IsEnabled" 
                            Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Note that this is all freehand, so you may need to adjust it a bit, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: I have lots of datatemplates so I can not use the TargetName property.

Comment: @MiklósBalogh: that's another argument for using a property then.  It will allow reuse throughout the application, will allow you to change the functionality later if (for instance) there are two conditions instead of one, and is a very simple solution.  It's analogous to the CommandExecutable property of a Relay Command.